# Interpretation when relative gain score is the outcome variable

Tags: difference-in-difference, pre-post-comparison

I have two groups - treatment and control - and I am analyzing the effect of a policy change with multiple treatment periods. My dependent variable is a relative gain score (i.e. yt - yt-1)/yt-1). I am not quite sure how to interpret the coefficient on my treatment dummy which is -0.014. Does this mean that for observations subject to the treatment the dependent variable decreases by on average 1.4 percentage points post treatment? Thank you for any suggestions!!